# What is the dependent variable of a relative fluorescence graph?

Tags: biochemistry, enzyme-kinetics, kinetics

So it was asked what was the dependent variable of this experiment. I know that as students, we're wired to think that the y-axis is the dependent variable while the x-axis is the independent variable (probably good that way, I dunno).

However, I thought that the dependent variable in this kinetics would be time. Since this has relative fluorescence from 100 to 0, isn't the change in fluorescence for all four conditions the same, while the only affected variable being rate (which in this experiment is more dependent on change in time)?

Sorry I can't give more information about the conditions of the experiment, it's a test question that I wouldn't be allowed to post, which is why I whited-out the conditions of each line. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When a variable is independent, it's not affected by any other variable. Relative fluorescence obviously depends on the time parameter in this case. If you stopped at 30 minutes and took readings ever 3 minutes, your data would look very different.

Without more information about the experiment, however, it's hard to tell if there are additional variables.